# How to parse JSON arrays with retrofit

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I have JSON file like this http://androiddocs.ru/api/friends.json

```
{
"data":"dbfriends",
"friends": [{"id":"1","name":"Andrew","city":"Moscow","contacts":{"mobile":"+7           0000000","email":"andrew@androiddocs.ru","skype":"andrew"}},       {"id":"2","name":"Ivan","city":"Kiev","contacts":{"mobile":"+38 0000000","email":"ivan@androiddocs.ru","skype":"ivan"}}]
}
```

my retrofit interface

```
public interface Friends_API {

    String BASE_URL = " http://androiddocs.ru/api/";

    @GET("friends.json") Call<Friends> getFriends();



    class Factory {

        private static Friends_API service;

        public static Friends_API getInstance(){
            if (service == null) {
                Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                        .build();

                service = retrofit.create(Friends_API.class);
                return service;
            } else {
                return service;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

POJO file generated by http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/
and my code to get data value and:

```
Friends_API.Factory.getInstance().getFriends().enqueue(new Callback<Friends>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<Friends> call, Response<Friends> response) {
        String getData = response.body().getData();
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<Friends> call, Throwable t) {

    }
}
```

i can't understood how i can get value: id, name, city...

thanks for help!

Comment: Retrofit already parsed the JSON using Gson. You have direct access to a Java object now

Comment: i can`t understand( how i can do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the data from retrieved response using:

```
Friends friends = response.body();
```

And then you can retrieve the `List<Friend>` using `friends.getFriends()` object. Now you can iterate through this list of friends and can get id,name, city or contact details.